# What is the name of this view or widget

Tags: android

[image: Screenshot of similar widget]

Please What is the name of this view, I want to use it,
i have a hierarchy of Labels and Edit Text, I would like to add a line that connects the labels and edit texts as shown in the image, I know of this widget normally used by developers but I don't its name.

Comment: That is not a widget. Its a custom made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is somewhat similar to **Bootstrap Wizard**. As per my knowledge, there is no official widget for this. However, you could find many libraries on GitHub, like:

https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView

https://github.com/transferwise/sequence-layout